# Class in gwt server package throwing ClasNotFound Exception while being called by Service class

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

During an RPC call to my service class, ChartService, I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when an object of class CustomChartData is being created. CustomChartData is in a package named "server.chart" in the same project. ChartService is, of course, in the "server" package of the project.

I've tried moving the CustomChartDataClass to the "server" package, but that didn't work. I've looked for similar problems, but the only ones I've found have to do with jars not being in the right place.

I'm using GWT 2.4, Java 1.6, and Eclipse Juno.

Has anybody come across something like this before? Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use CustomChartData on the client side to? If so, try to put the class in the package shared.chart

Comment: no, it's not used on the client side, it's meant to be used only on the server side. I tried putting it in the shared package anyways, it did not work